# Number of possible sums of the form $a+b$ where a and b are non negative integers less than a fixed n

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ where $x_i$ are non-negative integers. Let $A+A := \{x_i + x_j | 1\leq i,j \leq n\}. $ Then what is $|A+A|?$
Even if an exact expression cannot be determined, are there any tight bounds I can achieve here?
I have observed that if $A = \{0,1,...,n\}$ then $|A+A| = 2n+1.$ However when $A$ is not so specifically chosen then $|A+A|$ need not be equal to $2n+1.$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The example where $A = \{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$, or more generally, when $A$ is an arithmetic progression, gives the least possible size of $A+A$: it gives $|A+A|=2|A|-1$. That's the only case where this lower bound is achieved.

This lower bound is easy to prove: if $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n$, then $A+A$ has at least the $2n-1$ distinct elements $$x_1 + x_1 < x_1+x_2 <\dots < x_1 + x_n < x_2 + x_n < \dots < x_n + x_n.$$

On the other hand, a [Sidon set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence) such as $\{2^1, 2^2, 2^3, \dots, 2^n\}$ does not have any repeated sums. If $A$ is a Sidon set, we achieve the upper limit of $|A+A| = \binom{|A|+1}{2}$.

[Freiman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiman%27s_theorem) is one possible result that tells us that $A$ must be very rigidly structured for $|A+A|$ to be small (as a function of $|A|$).

Comment: Ah okay.. can you shed some light on what you mean when you say "rigidly structured" ?

Comment: In the case of Freiman's theorem, it means "contained in a relatively small generalized arithmetic progression". (A generalized arithmetic progression has more than one difference: something like $\{a + i d_1 + j d_2 : 0 \le i \le k_1, 0 \le j \le k_2\}$ is a generalized AP of rank $2$.)